# cache memory performance

Tags: memory, caching, cpu-architecture

i just have a general question about cache memory. How would a program perform badly on a cache based system ? , since cache memory stores adresses from main memory that is requested, aswell as adresses that ranges around the same adress as the one copied from the main memory.

Answer (score 5):

Read this: [What every programmer should know about memory (PDF)](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).